# Do we want to answer questions about the mechanical act of writing?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

[This question about cursive](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2852/is-there-any-point-in-learning-to-write-in-cursive) was migrated here from the skeptics site.  I understand why it doesn't fit there.  What I'm not sure of is whether or not it fits here.  My leaning is that this site focuses on what you are writing, not how you are doing it.  We answer some questions on the best tools to get the job done, but does that extend to longhand writing in cursive versus print?  We have closed at least one question asking for a pen recommendation before, but was that because it was a poll or because it was about pens or both?

What should our policy be?

Comment: While I agree with the answer below re writing tools, I'm afraid the question being referenced has NOTHING to do with being a writer. What does the origin, practicality or learning of cursive have to do with this site's stated objectives? I've voted to close the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So long as it doesn't come to dominate the site, and it's not *egregiously* off topic, it is probably OK.

Early in the life of a site, you can be a bit more flexible with the types of questions you allow, however, you do need to be careful that you're not allowing a "weed" into your garden that will grow unchecked and choke out other more practical plants.

Answer (score 9):

We've already had a few questions on writing tools, I'd say it's no different than talking about what kind of software we use (and we already had a Q. on handwriting vs. word processing for early drafts.

I was the one who gave the skeptics mods the OK to migrate.

Comment: Agree one million percent.

Comment: @HedgeMage - while your answer clearly shows the benefit to writers in writing cursive, the question that sparked my question is also attracting some rather poll-like answers.  One other non-software tools question did as well.  Maybe it's just those specific questions?

Comment: @justkt We still have some users that haven't quite grokked the SE format -- downvotes or edits and explanations seem to be in order.  I don't think the question itself is a poll, just the way some people chose to interpret it.

Comment: Seems to be a subjective question that has no answer to me. It'd be the same as asking "Is there any point to using Word for writing when I can just use Scrivener?" Everyone would have their own opinion on cursive vs print writing.

Comment: @Ralph - It might deserve better phrasing, like "are there any advantages to cursive writing over more modern methods like using typewriters, computers, etc.", but at the least the question of history is not subjective.

Comment: If it's rephrased like you suggested, I would have no problem with the question. But as it stands, it's a subjective opinion question.